# How can I clean up text files in python?

Tags: python, text

I have text in a file that looks like this:

```
text1 5,000 6,000
text2 2,000 3,000
text3 
           5,000 3,000
text4 1,000 2000
text5
          7,000 1,000
text6 2,000 1,000
```

Is there any way to clean this up in Python so that if there are missing numbers after a text line, the numbers on the subsequent line can be placed on the line above:

```
text1 5,000 6,000
text2 2,000 3,000
text3 5,000 3,000
text4 1,000 2000
text5 7,000 1,000
text6 2,000 1,000
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a one-time problem and the spacing is not quite as neat as I've shown here.

Comment: how can you formally tell where a new line begins and where previous continues? Judging on whitespace prefix of the line?

Comment: @ulidtko, yes, the whitespace indicates a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that logical lines "continue" on lines which start with whitespace (and contain arbitrary amount of records), you can use this:

```
>>> collapse_space = lambda s: str.join(" ", s.split())
>>>
>>> logical_lines = []
>>> for line in open("text"):
...   if line[0].isspace():
...     logical_lines[-1] += line #-- append the continuation to the last logical line
...   else:
...     logical_lines.append(line) #-- start a new logical line
... 
>>> l = map(collapse_space, logical_lines)
>>>
>>> print str.join("\n", l)
text1 5,000 6,000
text2 2,000 3,000
text3 5,000 3,000
text4 1,000 2000
text5 7,000 1,000
text6 2,000 1,000
```

Comment: this may sound like a dumb question and you might ask why I would ever want to do this, but say I only wanted to append the line for text3 with its corresponding numbers and leave the line for text5 without its numbers.  would I just add "if 'text3' in line" to the code?

Comment: I think I got it.  thanks again for the help.                      collapse_space = lambda s: str.join(" ", s.split())
logical_lines = []
data=open("test.txt").readlines()
for i,line in enumerate(data):
    if 'text3' in data[i-1] and line[0].isspace():
        logical_lines[-1] += line
    else:
        logical_lines.append(line)
l = map(collapse_space, logical_lines)
print str.join("\n", l)

Comment: @coderman, I'd have no single doubt about it if I done some one-time transforming of the file (which means yes, pretty much ok to do so). But if you are writing reusable code, you'd better abstracted that bit a little higher; say, write a function which takes "text5" as parameter and skips it in the body appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there should be exactly three "words" on each line, you could use

```
tokens = (x for line in open("file") for x in line.split())
for t in zip(tokens, tokens, tokens):
    print str.join(" ", t)
```

**Edit**: Since apparently the above prerequisite does not hold, here is an implementation that actually looks at the data:

```
from itertools import groupby
tokens = (x for line in open("file") for x in line.split())
for key, it in groupby(tokens, lambda x: x[0].isdigit()):
    if key:
        print str.join(" ", it)
    else:
        print str.join("\n", it),
```

Comment: Thanks @Sven Marnach.  Unfortunately, there will not always be 3 words on each line.

Comment: +1: I have just been rereading some PyCon presentations on generators and co-routines, and this answer made me smile.

Comment: Smart use of `zip` on generators!

Comment: Just curious why you use `str.join(" ", it)` instead of `" ".join(it)`?

Comment: @kevpie: I think `" ".join(it)` somehow backwards.  I would like most if there was a built-in `join()` and I could use `join(it, sep=" ")` or similar.

Comment: @kevpie personally I plainly dislike how it looks. Calling methods on literal objects is pretty much ok for me, but not *that* regularly. So I prefer `str.join`.

Comment: @ulidtko @sven-marnach, thx for the insight.  I learned about _join_ and _split_ together, so it made some sense to me. `'|'.join(mystring.split('\t'))`.  I do remember thinking it looked weird way back then.